# imported xcode generated swift header not found in .pch file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have recently added a `Swift` file to my `Objective-C` only project. Xcode created the necessary header files, including the `Objective-C` Generated Interface Header. Everything works fine if I `#import` this header file `"myProject-Swift.h"` to the `.m` file where I am accessing the Swift class I have added.

However I will want to eventually use this Swift class throughout my project, and to avoid importing it every single time, I wanted to add this `myProject-Swift.h` import file to my .pch prefix file.

However when I try to build my app after having added this, I get a `'myProject-Swift.h' file not found` error and the build fails.

Does this mean it is not possible to import this `myProject-Swift.h` in a `.pch` file?

Is it really only possible to do it in each `.m` file individually?

Comment: try cleaning build folder `shift+command+option+k` may include ..

Comment: yep, done that, and cleaned derived data folder

Comment: Did you managed this somehow ?